# in puppeteer ,when i send mail to someone. pdf not generating with image. it creates with blank header

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

The PDF file is generating with blank header.what should I do for generating PDF with the header image. 
when I hit node command couple of times. after a long time, it is generating with full PDF.
how to create HTML file to PDF with images. using puppeteer.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
/* const minimalcss = require('minimalcss');*/
var csstree = require('css-tree');
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://fabalacritas.com/report/report.html?id=85', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');
    await page.waitFor(30000);
    await page.pdf({ path: './test.pdf', format: 'Letter', printBackground: true, });
//const IMAGE_LOADING_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000 * 5;
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "css-tree": "^1.0.0-alpha.27",
    "csstree": "0.0.3",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "minimalcss": "^0.7.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.4.2",
    "pdfkit": "^0.8.3",
    "phantom": "^4.0.12",
    "puppeteer": "^1.0.0",
    "wkhtmltopdf": "^0.3.4"
}
```

Comment: add system, software/package versions used. And where possible some code you're using.

Comment: const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
/* const minimalcss = require('minimalcss');*/
var csstree = require('css-tree');
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://fabalacritas.com/report/report.html?id=85', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');
    await page.waitFor(30000);
    await page.pdf({ path: './test.pdf', format: 'Letter', printBackground: true, });
    //const IMAGE_LOADING_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000 * 5;
    await browser.close();
})();

Comment: please post coding comment into your question by modifying it. Be aware of the four whitespaces for code indentations (it becomes grey in view box).

Answer (score 0):

I encourage to avoid timeouts `await page.waitFor(30000);`, this impact performance over big test cases because could be 5 seconds or 30 seconds.
First play with the [try-puppeteer](https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/) site so you can see if this code works for you (just copy-paste):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://fabalacritas.com/report/report.html?id=85', { waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle2'] });
await page.emulateMedia('screen');
await page.pdf({ path: './test.pdf', format: 'Letter', printBackground: true, });
await browser.close();
```

Be aware that I removed the wait time and added a new option in the goto function `{ waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle2'] }` this will set a wait for the full load site. Note: Check if you really need networkidle2.

Now, this is how your code will look whit my changes:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
/* const minimalcss = require('minimalcss');*/
var csstree = require('css-tree');
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://fabalacritas.com/report/report.html?id=85', { waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle2'] });
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');
    await page.pdf({ path: './test.pdf', format: 'Letter', printBackground: true, });
//const IMAGE_LOADING_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000 * 5;
    await browser.close();
})();
```